# Sharing integer values among tab bar controllers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitabbarcontroller

In my iOS app I have a main window with a tab bar. Each tab has its own controller, so I have multiple .m files. How can I obtain `int` values from each of these .m files and display them in a different tab (separate .m file)?

Can `int` values be called globally?

I would like to display all of these different values on one page as an overview.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables for this. Either save the ints using `NSUserDefaults`, or send them using `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Both of these ideas require wrapping an `int` in an `NSNumber` first.